# Finite element for coupled 1D and 3D equations

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

This is a renewed post for [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140666/finite-element-heat-conduction-with-coupled-1d-and-3d-equations), since the old post is already 2 years old and the problem hasn't been solved completely.

The problem is to solve heat conduction with robin type boundary condition, which is coupled with a 1D equation. The 1D equation describes the heat convection between fluid flow in a pipe and the surface of the pipe. This equation is necessary, because I would like to determine not only the temperature distribution inside the solid domain, but also the fluid flow temperature distribution along the z-axis.

For simplification, let's ignore the pipe wall and only consider steady-state first. The domain is a cuboid with a half cylinder hole.

[image]

The equations are as follows:

Eq1: $ \Delta T(x,y,z) = 0 $

BC1: $ k \frac{\partial T(x,y,z)}{\partial n} = \alpha_a(T(x,y,z) - T_e) $ if $y = 0$

BC2: $ - k \frac{\partial T(x,y,z)}{\partial n} = \alpha_i(T(x,y,z) - T_e) $ if $y = H$

BC3: $ \frac{\partial T(x,y,z)}{\partial n} = 0 $ if $x = 0 $

BC4: $ \frac{\partial T(x,y,z)}{\partial n} = 0 $ if $x = \frac{L_p}{2} $

BC5: $ \frac{\partial T(x,y,z)}{\partial n} = 0 $ if $z = 0 $

BC6: $ \frac{\partial T(x,y,z)}{\partial n} = 0 $ if $z = l $

BC7: $ - k \frac{\partial T(x,y,z)}{\partial n} = \alpha_f (T(x,y,z) - T_f(z)) $ if $x^2 + (y - H_a )^2 = r_a^2$

Eq2: $ - c_W \rho_W \dot{V}_f \frac{dT_f(z)}{dz} = 2 \alpha_f \pi r_a (T_f(z) - T_m(z))$

where $T_m(z)$ should be the average temperature at position z in the internal curve,

$T_m(z) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} T[r_a \cos(\vartheta), H_a + r_a \sin(\vartheta), z] d \vartheta $

We could also simplify the $T_m(z)$ into $T_m(z) = T(0, H_a - r_a, z)$.

As we can see the difficulty is the coupling of 1D and 3D equation. @user21 suggested to transform $T_f$ into a 3D function and the problem can be bypassed. Although this method gives me results, the solution $T_f$ is not strictly 1D, thus the energy might not be conserved. I implemented @user21's suggestion with the following code.

```
(* constants *)
Lp = 0.25;
da = 0.02;
hi = 0.15;
ha = 0.15;
ks = 2.1;
alphaf = 1000;
alphai = 6;
alphaa = 0.6;
ra = da/2;
Hi = hi + ra;
Ha = ha + ra;
H = Hi + Ha;
cW = 4200;
rhoW = 1000;
kW = 0.6;
l = 1;
Vf = 10 Lp l/3600000;

(* mesh *)
pointsStructure = {{0, 0}, {Lp/2, 0}, {Lp/2, H}, {0, H}};
pointsPipeOuter = Table[ra {Cos[theta Degree], Sin[theta Degree]} + {0, Ha}, {theta, 90, -90, -20}];
{len1, len2} = Length /@ {pointsStructure, pointsPipeOuter};
contour = Table[{i, If[i == len1 + len2, 1, i + 1]}, {i, 1, len1 + len2}];
line1D = MeshRegion[Table[{i}, {i, 0, l, l/50.}], Line /@ Table[{i, i + 1}, {i, 50}]];
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> Join[pointsStructure, pointsPipeOuter], "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[contour]}];
mesh2D = ToElementMesh[bmesh, "MeshOrder" -> 1, MaxCellMeasure -> 5 10^-5];
mesh2D["Wireframe"];
region2D = MeshRegion[mesh2D["Coordinates"], Triangle /@ mesh2D["MeshElements"][[1, 1]]];
region3D = RegionProduct[region2D, line1D];
mesh3D = ToElementMesh[region3D(*,MaxCellMeasure\[Rule]0.05 10^-5*)]

(* equations and NDSolve *)
eq = {-Inactive[Div][{{-ks, 0, 0}, {0, -ks, 0}, {0, 0, -ks}}.
Inactive[Grad][t[x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}] == 
NeumannValue[alphai t[x, y, z], y == H] + 
 NeumannValue[alphaa t[x, y, z], y == 0] + 
 NeumannValue[alphaf (t[x, y, z] - tf[x, y, z]), 
  x^2 + (y - Ha)^2 == ra^2],
-cW rhoW Vf D[tf[x, y, z], z] == Pi da alphaf (tf[x, y, z] - t[x, y, z]),
DirichletCondition[tf[x, y, z] == 10, z == 0]};
{T, Tf} = NDSolveValue[eq, {t, tf}, Element[{x, y, z}, mesh3D]];
SliceContourPlot3D[Tf[x, y, z], "ZStackedPlanes", Element[{x, y, z}, mesh3D]]
```

[image]

Any idea to solve this problem is appreciated.

**Edit 1**

One thing I tried is to force the 3 dimensional $T_f$ to be 1D function by modifying the Eq2 into

$ \Big[c_W \rho_W \dot{V}_f \frac{\partial T_f(x, y, z)}{\partial z} + 2 \alpha_f \pi r_a (T_f(x, y, z) - T(x, y, z)) \Big]^2 + (\frac{\partial T_f(x, y, z)}{\partial x})^2 + (\frac{\partial T_f(x, y, z)}{\partial y})^2 = 0 $

```
eq = {-Inactive[Div][{{-ks, 0, 0}, {0, -ks, 0}, {0, 0, -ks}}.
Inactive[Grad][t[x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}] == 
NeumannValue[alphai t[x, y, z], y == H] + 
 NeumannValue[alphaa t[x, y, z], y == 0] + 
 NeumannValue[alphaf (t[x, y, z] - tf[x, y, z]), 
  x^2 + (y - Ha)^2 == ra^2],
(Pi da alphaf (tf[x, y, z] - t[x, y, z]) + cW rhoW Vf D[tf[x, y, z], z])^2 
+ D[tf[x, y, z], x]^2 + D[tf[x, y, z], y]^2 == 0,
DirichletCondition[tf[x, y, z] == 10, z == 0]};
{T, Tf} = NDSolveValue[eq, {t, tf}, Element[{x, y, z}, mesh3D]];
```

But the error `FindRoot::nosol: Linear equation encountered that has no solution.` occurs.

Comment: See the solution to a similar problem. Choose the option that suits you. I will help. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/193789/how-to-apply-different-equations-to-different-parts-of-a-geometry-in-pde

Comment: @AlexTrounev thank you for your advice. I'm trying to understand the code you wrote in that post. I found the Michael E2's approach quite interesting and easy. My concern is that my problem is a little bit more complicated, since the 1D equation contains the $T_m(z)$, which is the integral of the 3D solution or the solution at a specific point. I'm not sure if `NDSolve` can handle integral differential equation or use $T(0, H_a - r_a, z)$ in the equation.

Comment: This is a piece of cake. On this site there are many such problems solved. Why do not you want to calculate the flow of fluid in the pipe and heat transfer?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Because it would take too long for steady-state and transient case, and the temperature distribution is actually more important to me. A simplified method to calculate the convective heat transfer between the fluid and the pipe wall could save a huge amount of time.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Could you give me advice on how to handle this integral differential equation? I'm thinking about calculating the $T(x, y, z)$ and $T_f(z)$ iteratively with `NDSolve`: solve $T(x, y, z)$ first and then solve $T_f(z)$, repeating the procedure until the results converges. I could imagine that it would work nice for the steady-state case. For the transient case however, it would be trickier.

Comment: I posted a solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use the   method of the false transient and the simple  model `Tf[z]=T[0,Ha-ra,z]` to show the difference from the solution with the temperature `Tf[x,y,z]` defined in the volume.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];(*constants*)Lp = 0.25;
da = 0.02;
hi = 0.15;
ha = 0.15;
ks = 2.1;
alphaf = 1000;
alphai = 6;
alphaa = 0.6;
ra = da/2;
Hi = hi + ra;
Ha = ha + ra;
H = Hi + Ha;
cW = 4200;
rhoW = 1000;
kW = 0.6;
l = 1;
Vf = 10 Lp l/3600000;

(*mesh*)
pointsStructure = {{0, 0}, {Lp/2, 0}, {Lp/2, H}, {0, H}};
pointsPipeOuter = 
  Table[ra {Cos[theta Degree], Sin[theta Degree]} + {0, Ha}, {theta, 
    90, -90, -20}];
{len1, len2} = Length /@ {pointsStructure, pointsPipeOuter};
contour = 
  Table[{i, If[i == len1 + len2, 1, i + 1]}, {i, 1, len1 + len2}];
line1D = MeshRegion[Table[{i}, {i, 0, l, l/50.}], 
   Line /@ Table[{i, i + 1}, {i, 50}]];
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> Join[pointsStructure, pointsPipeOuter], 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[contour]}];
mesh2D = ToElementMesh[bmesh, "MeshOrder" -> 1, 
   MaxCellMeasure -> 10^-4];
mesh2D["Wireframe"];
region2D = 
  MeshRegion[mesh2D["Coordinates"], 
   Triangle /@ mesh2D["MeshElements"][[1, 1]]];
region3D = RegionProduct[region2D, line1D];
mesh3D = ToElementMesh[region3D(*,MaxCellMeasure\[Rule]0.05 10^-5*)]

(*equations and NDSolve*)
eq = {-Inactive[
       Div][{{-ks, 0, 0}, {0, -ks, 0}, {0, 0, -ks}}.Inactive[Grad][
        t[x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}] == 
    NeumannValue[alphai t[x, y, z], y == H] + 
     NeumannValue[alphaa t[x, y, z], y == 0] + 
     NeumannValue[alphaf (t[x, y, z] - tf[x, y, z]), 
      x^2 + (y - Ha)^2 == ra^2], -cW rhoW Vf D[tf[x, y, z], z] == 
    Pi da alphaf (tf[x, y, z] - t[x, y, z]), 
   DirichletCondition[tf[x, y, z] == 10, z == 0]};
{T, Tf} = NDSolveValue[eq, {t, tf}, Element[{x, y, z}, mesh3D]];
```

The method of the false transient

```
Tn[0][x_, y_, z_] := T[x, y, z]
Tfn[0][z_] := T[0, Ha - ra, z]
n = 3;
Do[Tn[i] = 
  NDSolveValue[{-Inactive[
        Div][{{-ks, 0, 0}, {0, -ks, 0}, {0, 0, -ks}}.Inactive[Grad][
         t[x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}] == 
     NeumannValue[alphai t[x, y, z], y == H] + 
      NeumannValue[alphaa t[x, y, z], y == 0] + 
      NeumannValue[alphaf (t[x, y, z] - Tfn[i - 1][z]), 
       x^2 + (y - Ha)^2 == ra^2]}, t, Element[{x, y, z}, mesh3D]]; 
 Tfn[i] = NDSolveValue[{-cW rhoW Vf D[tf[z], z] == 
     Pi da alphaf (tf[z] - Tn[i][0, Ha - ra, z]), tf[0] == 10}, 
   tf, {z, 0, 1}];, {i, 1, n}]
```

The solution quickly converges. You can see the difference with the original solution.The difference is not very large as can be seen from the figures.

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[Tfn[i][z], {i, 0, n}]], {z, 0, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]

Table[ContourPlot[Tn[i][x, y, .5], {x, 0, .125}, {y, 0, .32}, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, Contours -> 20, PlotLegends -> Automatic], {i,
   0, n}]
```

[image: figure 1]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This solution seems quite good for the steady-state case but would it also be suitable for the transient case?

Comment: For transient, this method works even better than `NDSolve[]` in the new version. I tested the method on an unsteady flow around a cylinder and on problems of thermal convection, see https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1433064

Comment: I have some difficulty for understanding the code you wrote for the unsteady flow with NS-equation. Could you please give me a brief how you implemented the explicit euler with `NDSolve[]`?

Comment: Mathematica has a good linear FEM solver. I used it to solve non-linear non-stationary problems. For this, I used a simple algorithm similar to an explicit Euler (in time). At each step, linear FEM solver and interpolation are used there. This is due to the fact that the time derivative enters the NSE linearly. Therefore, constructing a numerical algorithm is not difficult. But there are tricks. Therefore, I tested the algorithm very carefully.